# How to create dynamic URL without using anchor href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to create dynamic URL without using anchor href ?

```
<a name="link";href="php_files/category_template.php?x=<?php echo $link[$j];?>"><?php       echo $title[$j];?>
</a></li>
```

i have currently working read csv and make a page on fly so, I want to move another page without using href.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: why this `;` after `name` attribute `<a name="link";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `onclick` event of `JS` with `locatio.href` like  this

```
<div onclick="location.href='php_files/category_template.php?x=<?php echo $link[$j];?>';"> <?php echo $title[$j];?> </div>
```